# Perl: Returning value of Object Method Doesn't trigger "if" Statement

Tags: perl, oop

I'm trying to debug my program, and I want to send out notifications to a watcher if there are any notifications to get.

I have a method `Notify` that returns a list of files that the watcher wants to follow. My `debug` routine is just there to help me debug my program.

This works. I see the second `debug` routine printing out the value:

```
foreach my $watcher ($watch->Watcher) {
    debug qq(Sending out notifcations for ) . $watcher->User, 2;
    my @foo = $watcher->Notify;
    if (@foo) {
        debug qq(Change list to notify on: ) . join (", " => $watcher->Notify), 3;
        $watch->SendEmail($watcher);
    }
```

}

However, this fails:

```
foreach my $watcher ($watch->Watcher) {
    debug qq(Sending out notifcations for ) . $watcher->User, 2;
    if ($watcher->Notify) {
        debug qq(Change list to notify on: ) . join (", " => $watcher->Notify), 3;
        $watch->SendEmail($watcher);
    }
```

}

The difference between the first and second: In the first, I return `$watcher->Notify` to an array `@foo` and test on `@foo`. In the second, I test on the return value of `$watcher->Notify`.

The Notify subroutine looks like this:

```
sub Notify {
    my $self   = shift;
    my $change = shift;

    $self->{CHANGE} = [] if not exists $self->{CHANGE};
    if (defined $change) {
        push @{$self->{CHANGE}}, $change;
    }
    return sort @{$self->{CHANGE}};
}
```

---

### Wait a second...

Okay, as I was typing this question out, I realized that when I say `if ($watcher->Notify)`, I am returning into a scalar context, and when I say `@foo = $watcher->Notify`, I'm returning into a list context. Further testing with this:

```
foreach my $watcher ($watch->Watcher) {
    debug qq(Sending out notifcations for ) . $watcher->User, 2;
    my $foo = $watcher->Notify;   #Now a SCALAR and not a LIST
    if ($foo) {
        debug qq(Change list to notify on: ) . join (", " => $watcher->Notify), 3;
        $watch->SendEmail($watcher);
    }
```

}

Showed that `$foo` was null. Changing my method to:

```
sub Notify {
    my $self   = shift;
    my $change = shift;

    $self->{CHANGE} = [] if not exists $self->{CHANGE};
    if (defined $change) {
        push @{$self->{CHANGE}}, $change;
    }
    if (wantarray) {
       return sort @{$self->{CHANGE}};
    }
    else {
       return scalar @{$self->{CHANGE}};
   }
}
```

Now works. (Method now checks if I want an array and if I don't, it returns an explicit scalar).

The question is why.

I thought if I returned an array into a scalar context, Perl should either be automatically doing a `scalar` for me (and return the number of items in the array) or at least join all elements in the array with `$"` as a separator. (I assumed the first, but the latter would have also worked).

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say switch);
use Data::Dumper;

my @foo = qw(this that the other);

my $bar = @foo;

say "Bar = $bar   \@foo = @foo";
```

prints out:

```
Bar = 4   @foo = this that the other
```

Where did I go wrong? (I mean, besides selling all of my  Apple stock when the price went all the way up to $40/share).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You weren't returning an array.  You were returning the result of `sort` called in scalar context.  According to [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html):

> In scalar context, the behaviour of `sort()` is undefined.

Which means it gets to do anything it wants, including returning `undef`.

Comment: @MisterEd, according to the timestamps, it was 50 seconds ;)  But thanks.

Comment: @MisterEd: Because I returned a `sort @array` and not just `@array`. Drats. I recently stopped using checking the return with `wantarray` because I was told it wasn't necessary, and I guess it isn't until it is.

Answer (score 2):

Because you were returning the result of `sort` in scalar context:

From http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html:

> In list context, this sorts the LIST and returns the sorted list
>   value. In scalar context, the behaviour of sort() is undefined.

EDIT:  If you don't want to use `wantarray` you could change:

```
return sort @{$self->{CHANGE}};
```

to:

```
return @{ [sort @{$self->{CHANGE}}] };
```

Comment: Sorry `cjm` beat you by a few seconds. Thanks anyway. Yeah, I realize I can do the `@{[...]}` thing too, but to me `wantarray` is clearer, easier for others to understand and maintain, and no more inefficient.